# Is it possible to manipulate routing so it looks like a subdomain in mvc .net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, subdomain

Im wondering if there is a solution where I can set a controllers route to look like a subdomain, for example StoreController
(where store is a name off a specific store)

http://store.myDomain.com/{Parameter}/{Action}

Is this possible to do in MVC (asp.net) or do i have to create subdomains on the server? (<-- That is what I'm trying to work around)

... :)

Comment: Subdomains only exist as a server concept (DNS).  You cannot "fake" it.  Assuming you've set *up* the DNS properly for your subdomains, you [can indeed make ASP.NET/MVC routes consume them](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/05/20/aspnet-mvc-domain-routing.aspx).